# How to get a different output in textbox then what the user enters

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just recently started using `tkinter`, and my question is how do i get a different output in the widget then what the user enters. Currently my GUI prints whatever the user types in the entry box and prints what the user types into a textbox.

How would I go about making if a certain word is entered in the entry box a sentence would be printed instead of the actual word. Example: user types in `"cat"`, so it prints `"Hello I heard you like cats"` in the textbox

This is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

class Display(Frame):

    mGui = Tk()
    mGui.geometry("500x500-500-300")
    mGui.title("GUI")
    mlabel = Label(mGui, text="Welcome").pack()

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter)
        self.clearButton = Button(self, text="Clear text", command=self.clear_text)
        self.clearButton.pack()
        self.output = Text(self)
        self.output.pack()
        sys.stdout = self
        self.pack()

    def onEnter(self, Frame):
        print(self.entry.get())

    def write(self, txt):
        self.output.insert(END, str(txt))

    def clear_text(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, "end")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Display().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your `onEnter` function as follows

```
def onEnter(self, Frame):
        if self.entry.get().lower() == "cat":
            print("Hello I heard you like " + self.entry.get() + "s")
        else:
            print(self.entry.get())
```